# happybase connect to hbase get table information failed

Tags: python, hbase, happybase

I am new to hbase, want to use happybase followed the tutorial here: https://happybase.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user.html#establishing-a-connection
code is as following:

```
connection = happybase.Connection(host='10.0.0.11', port=16000);
connection.open()
table = connection.table('users')
list(table.scan())
```

but I always get the thrift problem:

```
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes
```

Anyone knows how to solve this problem? I am on linux. thx

Answer (score 1):

Start the thrift deamon

```
sudo /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-1.1.3/bin/hbase-daemon.sh start thrift
```

change hbase-daemon.sh2 path according to your machine

By default thrift listens at 9090 port

connect to hbase

```
connection = happybase.Connection()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're connecting to a Thrift daemon (you have to start that separately from HBase itself). Also make sure the Thrift transport (`transport=...` argument in Happybase) matches the one used by the server.